# .sh inserts a ? upon file generation

Tags: automation, mtrace

I am using a .sh file along with a cron job to automate MTRs every 5 minutes.  Using the below I get the information needed, but it is unusable because after every new file it inserts a ? to the file name.

```
#!/bin/sh
File_Name=`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M`.log
echo `date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M` >>/tmp/mtr/log/$File_Name
echo " " >> /tmp/mtr/`date +%Y%m%d`
echo "======================" >> /tmp/mtr/log/`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M`
date >> /tmp/mtr/log/`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M`
echo "======================" >> /tmp/mtr/log/`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M`
echo " " >> /tmp/mtr/log/`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M`
/usr/sbin/mtr -r 8.8.8.8 -c 4 >>/tmp/mtr/log/$File_Name
```

The file output looks as:

```
# ls
20160420-14:54?     20160420-15:56?      20160420-15:56.log??
20160420-14:54.log  20160420-15:56.log?  20160420-4:54.log
```

Any help to why these question marks are being inserted will help greatly.

Thanks